# Is there a rule for the order of indegree-outdegree pairs of a directed graph degree sequence?

Tags: graph-theory

Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph#Degree_sequence) says that the following directed graph:

[image]

has the following degree sequence (list of indegree, outdegree pairs):

$$\{(2, 0), (2, 2), (0, 2), (1, 1)\}$$

My question is, what makes $(2,0)$ come first? Could the first pair be $(2,2)$, e.g.:

$$\{(2, 2), (2, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1)\}$$

?

It is also written that:

> The degree sequence is a directed graph invariant so isomorphic directed graphs have the same degree sequence.

If there's no rule for the order of pairs, does it mean that a degree sequence $\{(2, 0), (2, 2), (0, 2), (1, 1)\}$ would be considered the same as the sequence $\{(2, 2), (2, 0), (0, 2), (1, 1)\}$ ? I guess no.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I've never actually heard of degree sequences for directed graphs, but it appears that (like with undirected graphs) the actual order in which the degrees are presented is more a matter of convention/taste instead of any mathematical importance.

Comment: I think in the definition of the graph the sets $V$ and $E$ are ordered, the have labels $1, .., n$ and the vertices are always listed in the order of the labels. The isomorphism statement should read: "The degree sequence is a directed graph invariant so isomorphic directed graphs have isomorphic degree sequences." Relabeling the vertices of a graph is an isomorphism but then the degree sequence should be relabed (and hence reordered) as well.

Comment: @quarague This makes me think that the order of the pairs is not important then. However, `the degree sequence is a directed graph invariant` to me means that the degree sequence is an intrinsic property of the graph itself, not dependant on any labels assigned to its vertices. Therefore why should I label a degree sequence anyway? This is a passage which I didn't fully understand.

Comment: @TheoBendit Do you mean that the pairs indeed must be ordered so that given two graphs with the same collection of pairs their degree sequences will be the same (same pairs in the same order), though the order of pairs is left to the "implementor" ? It doesn't look like the Wikipedia's example follows a particular order convention, though.

Comment: I'm just saying, fundamentally, degree sequences are unordered objects. They're more sets than actual sequences. How you choose to order them is an aesthetic choice primarily, and in the case of directed graphs, this has become convention. I don't really know, but it looks like there is no convention here, as you say.